How best to protect against stale data execution
I'm new to React.
But I had a (hopefully basic!!) query -
Say I have a React component:
const productionMode = useRef<boolean>(true);

if (productionMode) {
    callToProdEnvironment();
}

But my concern is, say I have some async function which changes the value of productionMode to false right after it passes the if.
This would mean that I would be making a call to my production environment, which could potentially be very problematic.
Now. I could totally add a check to callToProdEnvironment which checks once again that productionMode is true, but this seems a little repetitive. Maybe it totally isn't a bad thing though. Please let me know.
But this one really makes me scratch my head:
Take this example:
const aRef = useRef<MyCustomObject | undefined>(myObj);

if (aRef.current) {
    console.log(aRef.current.aProperty);
}

after (aRef.current) passes.. but due to an async operation that changes aRef's value (to undefined), then accessing .aProperty on an undefined would not work! And I can't exactly add extra protection there.
I saw a suggestion about doing something like:
const aRef = useRef<MyCustomObject | undefined>(myObj);

const current = aRef.current;

if (current) {
    console.log(current.aProperty);
}

But to my mind this is an even staler version of aRef.current...
I can't really get my head around this, and I'm aware it's probably a very fundamental concern about race-conditions/the issues with async executions. But I am new to all of this, like I say, and I just wanted a little bit of perspective! I've spent hours trying to make sense of it. I feel a bit stupid!

An async task completing cannot interrupt synchronous execution. JavaScript uses an event loop with task queuing so you won't ever run into concurrency issues like you describe

So, during my call to 'callToProdEnvironment', would productionMode still be the way it originally was in the if? Would productionMode only be allowed to change during this if-scope during periods of await etc inside this same if-scope? Sorry that's quite a lot, but the question did get closed.

That's correct unless callToProdEnvironment was itself asynchronous. There is absolutely no way any code could change productionMode before callToProdEnvironment() is called. Similarly, there's no way any code could change aRef.current before you access aRef.current.aProperty

During the await behaviour of an async function (like if callToProdEnvironment were async), the event loop seems to open itself up to async behaviour from everywhere (loosely using that term), meaning that the ref would be open to changes from async functions elsewhere in the app. That's what I think I understand. In such a case do you think it wise to re-ask the same if-condition after every await/setTimeOut etc etc? Just to keep yourself right? Nesting looks a little gross, but seems.. reasonable (?) given what I now know.

That's really down to how you want your application to behave. Dealing with race conditions is just part of software development
